# remote: error: GH006: Protected branch update failed for refs/heads/preprod

Tags: git, macos, github

I am stuck to Github issue which seems weired to me.

I have been using Github from past 2 years. Recently I occured one issue which is given below:

```
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (12/12), completed with 12 local objects.
remote: error: GH006: Protected branch update failed for refs/heads/preprod.
remote: error: Changes must be made through a pull request.
```

I am working in organization where we have kept our repo as **Private** Repo.

We have different environment repo such as (staging, preprod, prod / master)

We have 2 Authentication Rules.

1. Must be approved by one of the person
2. It has some protected branches like staging,preprod, prod/master.

I am unable to push to protected branch from few days. I am also part of the team to push the code in protected branch.

I am using MAC. I know this there are many solutions but it doesnt work for me.

**Update (28 November 2023):
Forget to update here the best around way to resolve the issue.**

- If you are not able to resolve the issue then quick fix will be to create a new branch from the branch you were not allowed to push the changes and merge the current branch in newly created branch.
  (Eg. A is preprod branch and B is your feature/123 branch then create new branch from preprod branch named as feature/123-preprod. Now merge your changes of feature/123 branch in feature/123-preprod branch and push the changes to remote. After this create PR against preprod with newly branch feature/123-preprod.)
- In this particular scenario there will be no RMC and you can easily merge the changes in preprod.
- Also dont forget to delete the feature/123-preprod branch after your deployment to avoid confusion.
- This is will only work if you have selected only few selected branches under protected branch.

Comment: Well, I know i have created PR for same against the pushing protected branch

Comment: No thats bad habit as i said I need my code push to preprod branch and suppose I make a new branch from preprod instead of master then this will create problem when we push code to master branch.

Comment: I am sorry to say we cannot do, even I have been worried how this is suddenly not working for me to push to protected branches. I have also remove github from key access and tried to add again credentials still after do that its not working from Sublime Merge or Terminal.

Comment: Good update. I have referenced it (and summarized it) in [my own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76548242/6309).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That means the [rules](https://github.blog/changelog/label/rules/) ([in beta in April 2023](https://github.blog/changelog/2023-04-17-introducing-repository-rules-public-beta/)) are now in effect for all repositories.

Make sure to follow "[Enhancements for admins bypassing branch protections on `github.com`](https://github.blog/changelog/2023-04-20-enhancements-for-admins-bypassing-branch-protections-on-github-com/)"

Or, as shown in this [discussion yesterday (June 23, 2023)](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/58914#discussioncomment-6266162), you would need to remove the rule:

[image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/5814919/248411819-7859c48b-3f2e-4ba6-b072-c6f0ec9c3027.png]

---

The [OP 000723-weict](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17731528/000723-weict) suggests a workaround using branching and pull requests, which is different from my approach focused on understanding and potentially adjusting repository rules and branch protections.

The OP suggests creating a new branch (e.g., `feature/123-preprod`) from the protected branch (`preprod`), then merging the changes from the original feature branch (`feature/123`) into this new branch. That method bypasses the direct push restrictions on the protected branch by using an intermediary branch for merging changes.
A pull request is then created to merge the intermediary branch into the protected branch. The intermediary branch is deleted after successful deployment to maintain clarity in the repository.

My approach involves understanding and utilizing the new GitHub rules and enhancements for admins bypassing branch protections. But it might require administrative access or changes to the repository rules, which might not always be feasible.

Comment: Sure , I will check this out but it allows me merge branches without RMC(Resolve Merge Conflict) from github , but when I do RMC from my terminal locally its sends back this error, although I have created Pull Request against that same protected branch. Any clue on this because its hard to digest this working :(

Comment: @000723-weict OK. I rarely used [RMC](https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/addressing-merge-conflicts/resolving-a-merge-conflict-on-github), because I always rebase my branch on top of the PR target branch: I resolve conflict locally, then force push my branch. The PR has then only a trivial merge to do. No RMC required.

Comment: is there any chances that i am not part of that project and repo is private due to which doesnt allow to push to protected branches? @VonC

Comment: @000723-weict I suppose. But you must have some rights, if you were able to push to a protected branch before. You might have checked the "Allow Specified actors to bypass required pull requests" option is active, but are you listed as one of the specified actors? If yes, then in theory, you should be able to push directly to the protected branch.  
Double-check if there are any other branch protection rules or GitHub Actions that might be interfering with your ability to push to the protected branch.

Answer (score 0):

You did not mentioned what access you have for those repositories (admin/contributor) ?

In the branch protection rules there is a flag which helps to by pass the pull request check,

Protect matching branches -> Require a pull request before merging -> **Allow Specified actors to bypass required pull requests**.

There might be a possibility that you had this special access to push to repository and recently it got revoked by GitHub repository administrator.

Comment: I have done this already and confirmed by my admin Protect matching branches -> Require a pull request before merging -> Allow Specified actors to bypass required pull requests.